# Como faço para liberar o botão quando o usuário clicar em qualquer parte do site?

Tags: javascript, php, html

gostaria que quando o usuário entrasse em uma página aparecesse no caso um botão de bloqueado pedindo para ele clicar em qualquer canto da página para liberar este botão.

No caso o código do botão seria este: (no caso ja é o codigo do botão liberado so que queria deixar ele bloqueado no primeiro acesso, e so liberasse apos o primeiro click)

```
       <div id="ccontainer" class="container">
        <div class="esq">
            <div class="conteudo">
            <div class="box-alert">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
                    <b style="margin-top: 5px;"; >APERTE EM ACESSAR E VC SERIA REDIRECIONADO A UMA NOVA PAGINA </br> ⬇️</b></div>
                    <h5 style="color:blue" font-family="Impact"><a href="<?=base64_decode($_POST["token"]);?>" class="w3-btn w3-block w3-red" target="_blank">ACESSAR</a></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Se você quer que ao clicar em qualquer canto da página, o botão seja habilitado, então você deve colocar o evento de click no elemento html propriamente dito.

Um exemplo para você executar e ver se é o que você precisa:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#btnHappy');

(() => button.disabled = true)();

const enable= () => button.disabled = false;

const html = document.querySelector('html');
html.addEventListener('click', enable);
```

```html
<label>Clique em qualquer canto para ativar o botão:</label>
<button id="btnHappy">BOTÃO DA FELICIDADE</button>
```

No teu caso, eu colocaria uma *id* no elemento **a**, ficaria assim:

```
<a id=btnAccess" href="<?=base64_decode($_POST["token"]);?>" class="w3-btn w3-block w3-red" target="_blank">ACESSAR</a>
```

Acima, o nome da *id* foi "btnAccess".

E depois colocaria o javascript para desabilitar ao início:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#btnAccess');
(() => button.disabled = true)();
```

E depois o javascript para habilitar quando clicar em alguma parte do site:

```
const enable = () => button.disabled = false;
const html = document.querySelector('html');
html.addEventListener('click', enable);
```